# Does the order of SqlCommand Parameter & CommandText declaration matter?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using the `SqlCommand` object to read from/write to my database. I know that using SQL commands like below could lead to trouble:

```
Select * from myTable where tableId = '" + tableID + "'";
```

Instead, I've been using the preferred method of commands like:

```
Select * from myTable where tableId = @Table_ID";
```

Then create my parameters:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Table_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = tableID;
```

I have two questions:

1. Is the order that I add my parameters to the `SqlCommand` object important?
2. Do I need to add my `SqlCommand.CommandText` string before I add my parameters?

I've always added my `CommandText` first and then added my parameters in order that they are used in the SQL string, but there are times where I would like to select from two different SQL strings (example: insert vs. update), but then add all the parameters after the "If" statement instead of nesting them inside it.

Comment: `SqlCommand` is based on **ADO.NET** technology - and the SQL Server parameters are **named parameters** - so no, the sequence in which you add them to the `SqlCommand.Parameters` collection does **NOT** matter. And also: initialising the `CommandText` is independent of the parameters - you can do it before or after - doesn't matter. It all comes together at the time you **execute** the query.  **OleDB** (for accessing e.g. MS Access - using `OleDbCommand` class) however uses **positional parameters** - not named ones - there the order **IS** important!

Comment: You should probably clarify that your question is specific to SQL Server (it looks that way), as the parameter ordering question appears to depend on that,per @marc_s's comment.

Comment: @CoolBots: the use of `SqlCommand` implies SQL Server - `SqlCommand` and related classes are **SQL Server ONLY** ....

Comment: @marc_s that's a good point! Your comment mentioned Access, which made me doubtful, lol. Although, thank you for the comment - I didn't know `OleDbCommand` is positional parameters only.

Comment: `Is the order that I add my parameters to the SqlCommand object important?` why assume the order is important; are you seeing problems? `Should I add command text before I add my parameters` are you having issues where adding it before adding your params or after? I am having a hard time looking into your question because nothing in the context explains otherwise; I'm not seeing a specific issue here.

Comment: Also IMHO use stored procedures there are many benefits to list here as to why use them.

Answer (score 5):

1. No, the parameters do not need to be added in the order that they appear in the text, *as long as they are named parameters*
2. It's not necessary to add the `CommandText` to the `SqlCommand` before the parameters

Answer (score -2):

You don't need the command to be initialized with the command text first before adding parameters.

The order of parameters is not important if you are using named parameters like @Table_ID as you seem to be doing. The order is important if you are using positional parameters.

This depends on the Data access client you are using.

System.Data.SqlClient: Uses named parameters in the format @parametername.

System.Data.OleDb: Uses positional parameter markers indicated by a question mark (?).

System.Data.Odbc: Uses positional parameter markers indicated by a question mark (?).

System.Data.OracleClient: Uses named parameters in the format :parmname (or parmname).

Yes, you can set the command text conditionally (insert or update) and then add the parameters outside the conditional.

Comment: Why do you need to have the command initialized with command text first?